# SCSS mixin, how to concatenate units? (px,%,em)

Tags: css, sass, mixins, compass

I want to define classes like

```
.bg-1 {
   width: 1%
}
.bg-2 {
   width: 2%
}
```

And I'm trying with this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {    
  .bg-#{$i} {
    width: #{$i};
  }
}
```

This at least compiles, but prints out

```
    .bg-1 {
       width: 1;
    }
    .bg-2 {
       width: 2;
    }
```

the problem is that If I add:

```
width: #{$i}%;
```

I got:

> ```
> error sass/screen.scss (Line 294 of sass/modules/_classes.scss: Invalid CSS after "   $var: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "%;")
> ```

Comment: Try `width: #{$i} + '%';` or `width: #{$i}'%';`

Comment: This generates  `.bg-95{width:95+"%"}` or `.bg-95{width:95"%"}`...

Comment: @cimmanom If you mean that i should `$percent: 1%` and then 'width: #{$i}*$percent;` I tried before asking... and the result was `.bg-95{width:95*1%"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution. It works.

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {    
   .bg-#{$i} {
     $percentage: unquote("%");
     width: #{$i}$percentage;
   }
}
```

Or this:

```
 @for $i from 1 through 100 {    
  .bg-#{$i} {
    width: #{$i}unquote("%");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Or something like this, which is more popular.

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {    
  .bg-#{$i} {
    width: round(percentage($i/100)); // Math function
    height: #{$i}px; // For px or em just concat
  }
}
```